# Multiple inheritance and "this" pointer being cast to common base class

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
class Base {
  //some code
};

class A : public virtual Base{
    //some code
};

class B : public virtual Base{
    //some code
};

class C:  public A, public B {
    //some code
};
```

In other words we have multiple inheritance and all classes inherit from class Base. Now consider that the "this" pointer exists in code in classes A,B,C,Base. I know that in general we cannot assume that the "this" pointer value will be identical in all cases. But what it the "this" pointer is cast to the Base* class inside A,B,C whenever it is used. Is it correct to say that the casted pointer "this" after casting to the common Base* class will contain the same address inside A,B,C? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The virtual inheritance means that there is only one base class subobject of type `Base`, which is simultaneously a subobject of the `C` and the `A` and the `B`. A conversion (implicit or by cast) from pointer to any of those types to `Base*`, or initializing a reference `Base&` from lvalue of any of those types will cause the compiler to do the correct logic to find that single `Base` subobject.

Answer (score 0):

> But what it the "this" pointer is cast to the Base* class inside A,B,C whenever it is used

Note that there isn't even a need to cast (i.e. convert explicitly). A pointer to derived converts to base pointer implicitly.

> Is it correct to say that the casted pointer "this" after casting to the common Base* class will contain the same value inside A,B,C?

A pointer doesn't "contain values" other than the value of the address of an object. The object whose address is stored is the pointed object. A pointer to a base points to the base sub object.